# List with patterns virtual machine names for playbook exclusion

Tags: ansible

I have some VMs that should be excluded from all playbooks. I create role with main task:

```
vars:
  exclusion_patterns:
    - pattern1
    - pattern2
tasks:
  - name: End play for exclusion hosts
    meta: end_host
    with_items: "{{ exclusion_patterns }}"
    when: "{{ item }} in inventory_hostname"
```

Next, i want import this role in first task playbooks and skip vm with patterns from "exclusion_patterns" in inventory_hostname.
But Ansible get error: variable item is not defined.
Any variants?

Answer (score 0):

1) Let's create the list of excluded hosts and loop the list.

```
- hosts: all_hosts_to_select_from
  vars:
    exclusion_patterns:
      - pattern1
      - pattern2
  tasks:
    - name: Create list of excluded hosts
      set_fact:
        excluded_hosts: "{{ excluded_hosts|default([]) + ansible_play_hosts_all|
                                                         select('match', item)|
                                                         list }}"
      loop: "{{ exclusion_patterns }}"
      run_once: true
    - name: End play for exclusion hosts
      meta: end_host
      loop: "{{ excluded_hosts }}"
      run_once: true
```

(not tested)

2) It's also possible to create the inventory group of included hosts in the first play and use it in the second.

```
- name: No.1 Create group of included hosts
  hosts: all_hosts_to_select_from
  vars:
    exclusion_patterns:
      - pattern1
      - pattern2
    included_hosts: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all }}"
  tasks:
    - name: Remove excluded hosts fromt the list
      set_fact:
        included_hosts: "{{ included_hosts|
                            difference(ansible_play_hosts_all|
                                       select('match', item)|
                                       list)
                            }}"
      loop: "{{ exclusion_patterns }}"
      run_once: true
    - name: Create group of included hosts
      add_host:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        groups: group_of_included_hosts
      loop: "{{ included_hosts }}"
      run_once: true

- name: No.2 Run group of included hosts
  hosts: group_of_included_hosts
  tasks:
    - name: List ansible_play_hosts_all
      debug:
        var: ansible_play_hosts_all
      run_once: true
```

(not tested)

Comment: Thanks! It possible without `hosts: all_hosts_to_select_from`? It should be single task in role.

Comment: Sure. `all_hosts_to_select_from`  is only to tell in the example that these are the hosts we select from. The tasks can be used in a role without any modification. Test it. If you have troubles update the question. Make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) whenever possible.